# SQL Server stored procedure to report progress to its caller, an Access (VBA DAO) pass through query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, dao, progress

Is there way for a SQL Server stored procedure to report progress to the caller?
I have a complex task consisting of multiple steps, and I have a stored procedure that does it. I call this stored procedure from a MS Access front-end. The stored procedure takes about 3-4 minutes to finish, during which period Access seems to "hang", waiting for the stored procedure to return a result or time out.

I know I could take my stored procedure apart into 3-4 little pieces, and call them one after the other, providing some feedback between the steps. This however feels like a workaround, not a solution.

I'd also hate to have four stored procedures instead of just one, because I have many tasks like this, and this path would turn my 30 stored procedures (already numerous) into 50+.

So, is there any way for a stored procedure to occasionally report back to the calling Access (DAO) with a status or anything?

Here is how I call the stored procedure:

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
' get .Connect property from existing ODBC linked table
qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("Quote").Connect
qdf.sql = "EXEC INV.ProcessMatchedQueries"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.ODBCTimeout = 300
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there no good solution.

Try to execute one SP to do your job (with `dbRunAsync`) and another SP to receive result status. First SP should store execution status somewhere and second SP will read it.

Comment: This is actually a good idea, I'll try that. I'll leave the question open for a while in hopes of another, prettier solution. Thank you!

Comment: In ADO.NET you can create a `SqlDataReader` object to receive multiply recordsets and add multiply `SELECT` statements in one SP to return result status. I think it's not supported in DAO.